# How secure is my hashing algorithm?

Tags: php, security, md5

I am writing a website for personal use (I hope but don't think anyone will ever come there), and developed the following algorithm:

```
function encryptPassword($username, $password) {
    $username=md5($username);
    $password=md5($password);

    $newpass = substr($username, 0, 5) . $password . substr($username, 5 );
    $newpass = md5($newpass);

    return $newpass;
}
```

Since it still is a kind of 'know the password and you're in' kind of system (as usual though), I think it would be a better idea to hide the password in the database.

I have previously used the simple MD5x1 algorithm (basically: md5(pass) and done) but then people with access to the database would easily be able to reverse hash it. This way I don't think you're able to reverse hash this thing.

Comment: As always with these things: fail. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Are hashing algorithms supposed to be secure? I thought they were just supposed to perform a hash and not some type of encryption.

Comment: It is _thoroughly_ insecure.

Comment: @j08691: Yes; read about cryptographic hashes on Wikipedia.

Comment: It's not, give it up **now**.

Comment: don't reinvent *(as other's have stated)*. `MD5` is old. you're better off with `SHA256`/`SHA512`

Comment: How is my hashing algorithm?  Bad.

Comment: No one even has to look past the title. If you have to ask Stack Overflow if the algorithm you designed is secure, it's not. In fact, if PhD candidates aren't coming to **you** to ask your advice about security, nothing you design is likely to be secure.

Comment: MD5 is already broken.

Comment: **Do not use MD5 as a secure hash algorithm.**  MD5 is a *message digest*, not a secure hash algorithm.  You should consider using `crypt()` with a salt instead.

Comment: What stops you from using a very simple and many times more secure `verify_password` function that the language now provides? http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not.

1. MD5 is cryptographically weak.
2. Salts should be random, not derived from known values.
3. One round of hashing is trivial to break these days.

Solutions to the above:

1. Use a better algorithm, preferably SHA2 or better.
2. Generate random salts.
3. Hash multiple rounds

Oh wait, there's already an entire library built into PHP that does this, except *way* better. It's [`password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), and if you're using a version of PHP earlier than 5.5 when it was implemented there's [`password_compat`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) which backports it as far back as 5.3.7, and if *that* still doesn't work you really need to update your PHP install.

Lastly, unless you have college-level education in cryptography you should never attempt to 'roll your own' hashing or encryption schemes. 99% of the time you will end up with a far less secure system than if you had used something industry-standard.

Comment: Yes to all of the above. Adding: Successful hashing algorithms are released to the public, vetted by security experts, and then eventually (maybe!) recommended for use in production sites. Don't roll your own crypto.

Comment: @Sammitch posted the correct answer. Please accept it. :)